# Rails: Devise login route conflicting with sessions resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I having an issue logging in after a successful signup using Devise with rails.

I get this error.

No route matches [POST] "/sessions/user"

I'm not sure why. I have a model named 'session' could this be why?

Here is the view-

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to current_user.full_name, edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
</ul>
```

And here is the output from 'rake routes'

```
 new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
            sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)            sessions#index
                     POST   /sessions(.:format)            sessions#create
         new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)        sessions#new
        edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)   sessions#edit
             session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#show
                     PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#update
                     DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#destroy
                root        /                              sessions#index
```

I've searched around but haven't found any duplicates, If you catch something here please let me know. Thanks for your help on this.

The sign in page-

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span4">
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name),     html: {class: "well"} ) do |f| %>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Sign in</legend>

      <%= f.input :email %>
      <%= f.input :password %>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div><%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean %> </div>
    <% end -%>

    <div><%= f.button :submit, "Sign in" %></div>
  </fieldset>  
  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>

  <div class="span8">
    <h2>Signing in is easy and secure!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the error happens?

Comment: Yes, apologies. Whenever I register, sign out, then try to sign back in with the user I just created. I receive the error.

Comment: Still stuck please help, I don't mind searching or reading for the answer if someone can point me in the right direction. I just need to know that direction and not spend (another) 6 hours thinking I'm getting it.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. What action do you take when you say "try to sign back in"? Do you mean that you're clicking the login link for the view? Are you filling out a login form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Devise defines a method session_path which is conflicting with your own routes: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb#L9

You'll need to either rename your Session model or provide a different name when you specify the routes for your Session model. Something like:

```
# routes.rb
resources :sessions, as: :logins
```

Comment: I ended up renaming the model.